# How can I arrange elements inside a wrapper like the example below?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I need to arrange following elements as [This sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMrR.jpg) with CSS Flexbox.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element large"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element large"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried few styles but couldn't get successful. Is there any way to fix this with css flex?

Comment: The grid is your friend.

Comment: @VXp Still I have to stick to Flex. Is there any way to do this with Flex?

Comment: Let me tell you something, there's a way + but not with the current HTML structure. :)

Comment: @VXp I know. Sill cannot find it :D

Comment: Wrap the smaller elements. example: https://jsfiddle.net/w9a099p9/  -- but this is what Grid was made for.

Comment: I think this solution by @Temani Afif can be a good point of start  [https://jsfiddle.net/6djrwkud/](https://jsfiddle.net/6djrwkud/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 Doesn't apply here, different case.

Comment: ok, so he can use grid :)

Comment: I couldn't find a proper solution using flex. So, thinking of using Grid. Browser support is something to think. Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you change your mind, the ***Grid*** solution:

```css
.grid {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px); /* "width" */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px); /* "height" */
  grid-gap: 10px; /* gap between items */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally centered */
}

.item {
  background: green;
}

.larger {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2; /* starts at the 1st column & spans two */
  grid-row: 1 / span 2; /* starts at the 1st row & spans two */
  /* can also omit the 1's since it's the first child */
}

.larger2 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item larger"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item larger2"></div>
</div>
```